# cypress-iframe error '$frame.prop is not a function'

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, cypress-iframe

I'm getting the following error when trying to use cypress-iframe: `$frame.prop is not a function`

The error is happening in cypress-iframe/dist/index.js on the 4th line in the excerpt below.  As you can see by the lines above it, it seems the iframe is being found.

```
if ($frame.length !== 1) {
    throw new Error("cypress-iframe commands can only be applied to exactly one iframe at a time.  Instead found " + $frame.length);
}
contentWindow = $frame.prop('contentWindow');
```

The versions I'm using:

```
"cypress": "^13.3.3",
"cypress-iframe": "^1.0.1",
```

Comment: cypress-iframe was last published 4 years ago and tested with  "cypress": "^3.8.3".

Comment: Are you using `cy.frameLoaded()` or `cy.iframe()`?

Comment: @Burkhalter I have tried both and get the same error either way.